# Return results within a given radius using a bounding circle as a 'First Cut' in MySQL

Tags: php, mysqli, pdo

I was working with Chris Veness' scripts from http://www.movable-type.co.uk  I was trying to run a query against a MySQL database to return only rows that fall within a given radius, using his [Bounding Circle](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong-db.html) script. As follows:

```
<?php 

require 'inc/dbparams.inc.php';  // defines $dsn, $username, $password
$db = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password);
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

$lat = $_GET['lat']; // latitude of centre of bounding circle in degrees
$lon = $_GET['lon']; // longitude of centre of bounding circle in degrees
$rad = $_GET['rad']; // radius of bounding circle in kilometers

$R = 6371;  // earth's mean radius, km

// first-cut bounding box (in degrees)
$maxLat = $lat + rad2deg($rad/$R);
$minLat = $lat - rad2deg($rad/$R);
// compensate for degrees longitude getting smaller with increasing latitude
$maxLon = $lon + rad2deg($rad/$R/cos(deg2rad($lat)));
$minLon = $lon - rad2deg($rad/$R/cos(deg2rad($lat)));

$sql = "Select Id, Postcode, Lat, Lon,
            acos(sin(:lat)*sin(radians(Lat)) + cos(:lat)*cos(radians(Lat))*cos(radians(Lon)-:lon)) * :R As D
        From (
            Select Id, Postcode, Lat, Lon
            From MyTable
            Where Lat Between :minLat And :maxLat
              And Lon Between :minLon And :maxLon
        ) As FirstCut
        Where acos(sin(:lat)*sin(radians(Lat)) + cos(:lat)*cos(radians(Lat))*cos(radians(Lon)-:lon)) * :R < :rad
        Order by D";
$params = array(
    'lat'    => deg2rad($lat),
    'lon'    => deg2rad($lon),
    'minLat' => $minLat,
    'minLon' => $minLon,
    'maxLat' => $maxLat,
    'maxLon' => $maxLon,
    'rad'    => $rad,
    'R'      => $R,
);
$points = $db->prepare($sql);
$points->execute($params);
?>

<html>
<table>
<? foreach ($points as $point): ?>
<tr>
    <td><?= $point->Postcode ?></td>
    <td><?= number_format($point->D,1) ?></td>
    <td><?= number_format($point->Lat,3) ?></td>
    <td><?= number_format($point->Lon,3) ?></td>
</tr>
<? endforeach ?>
</table>
</html>
```

I renamed my existing columns in my database to match what Chris Veness used - and instead of using a $_GET value, I entered some static values of

- $lat = 51.552971553688500;
- $lon = -3.028690575475280;
- $rad = 25;

This did not work... And moreover, I could not find a solution as to *why* it wasn't working, exactly... Although I think @dan08 was very much onto something with his answer below. He knows a lot more about this stuff than I do.

Despite all that - I do [finally] have a working solution! Please see my answer below.

Comment: mysqli and pdo just talk to mysql. the actual query itself doesn't really change at all (except maybe the specific types of placeholders you use in a prepared statement). there's absolutely no reason that `select * from foo` would behave differently in the two libraries, unless something at the "meta" level is different, e.g. different accounts. you are, however, re-using placeholder names, which isn't permitted.

Comment: Error 500, check your logs.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Storing user's location in DB and find the nearest users for him](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15010113/storing-users-location-in-db-and-find-the-nearest-users-for-him)

Comment: I don't think you can put parameters in the SELECT clause (or the FROM clause) because the parameters are added after the query plan is made, and the SELECT and FROM clauses are needed for the query plan, that can't have placeholders. [This guy explains it well](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php#111977)

Comment: Thank you for such swift responses, thus far. I will certainly try out some of your suggestions today and report back. @David Strachan, please would you kindly remove the duplicate tag as that question isn't referring to a bounding circle or first cut. Rather it just goes through every record in the database and spits out the nearest by their closest proximity. I already have that ability, but now I'm trying to do a FirstCut on those results to make my operation run much more rapidly. But thank you for the suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those folks over at Google Devs are clever bunch!

So here's the link I followed to find my solution: [Creating a Store Locator with PHP, MySQL & Google Maps](https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlsearch_v3?csw=1)

Despite the fact that this tutorial is geared toward using Google Maps API, the first half of the tutorial focuses on using PHP to query a database and create a bounding circle in order to search for matches within a given radius and return only those results that match.

In the tutorial, the query is super-fast and outputs the results in XML which is exceptionally useful for integrating into API. I didn't need that functionality, so I simplified mine a little.

Here's what I have - and it works perfectly for what I need:

Create a page called: **phpsqlsearch_dbinfo.php**

```
<?
$username="Your_Database_Username";
$password="Your_Database_Password";
$database="The_Name_of_Your_Database";
?>
```

Create a new page called: **phpsqlsearch_genxml.php**

When visiting this page, We pass some values to it, as we're using $_GET to collect the 'lat','lng' and 'radius' values.

Eg.**phpsqlsearch_genxml.php?lat=37&lng=-122&radius=25**

```
<?php  
require("phpsqlsearch_dbinfo.php");
// Get parameters from URL
$center_lat = $_GET["lat"];
$center_lng = $_GET["lng"];
$radius = $_GET["radius"];

// Opens a connection to a mySQL server
$connection=mysql_connect (localhost, $username, $password);
if (!$connection) {
  die("Not connected : " . mysql_error());
}
// Set the active mySQL database
$db_selected = mysql_select_db($database, $connection);
if (!$db_selected) {
  die ("Can\'t use db : " . mysql_error());
}
// Search the rows in the markers table
$query = sprintf("SELECT id, address, name, lat, lng, ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians('%s') ) * cos( radians( lat ) ) * cos( radians( lng ) - radians('%s') ) + sin( radians('%s') ) * sin( radians( lat ) ) ) ) AS distance FROM candidates HAVING distance < '%s' ORDER BY distance LIMIT 0 , 20",
  mysql_real_escape_string($center_lat),
  mysql_real_escape_string($center_lng),
  mysql_real_escape_string($center_lat),
  mysql_real_escape_string($radius));
$result = mysql_query($query);
if (!$result) {
  die("Invalid query: " . mysql_error());
}
while ($row = @mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
  $ID = mysql_real_escape_string($row['id']);
  $name = mysql_real_escape_string($row['name']);
  $address = mysql_real_escape_string($row['address']);
  $lat = mysql_real_escape_string($row['lat']);
  $lng = mysql_real_escape_string($row['lng']);
  $distance = mysql_real_escape_string($row['distance']);

  echo $name .", ". $address .", Latitude:". $lat .", Longitude:". $lng .", Distance From Home = ". round($distance)." Miles <br /><br />";

   // I then insert these matches into a new table for later use. 
   $new = "INSERT INTO matrix (Marker_ID, Cand_Name, Distance)
    VALUES ('$ID', '$name', '$distance')";

   $resulting = mysql_query($new);
   if (!$resulting) {
     die("Invalid query: " . mysql_error());
   }   
}
?>
```

Finally, to get this example working, you need to have your database set up.
If you don't have access to phpMyAdmin or prefer using SQL commands instead, here's the SQL statement that creates the table:

```
CREATE TABLE `markers` (
`id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY ,
`name` VARCHAR( 60 ) NOT NULL ,
`address` VARCHAR( 80 ) NOT NULL ,
`lat` FLOAT( 10, 6 ) NOT NULL ,
`lng` FLOAT( 10, 6 ) NOT NULL
) ENGINE = MYISAM ;
```

Now for the example data to populate the table: [Click Here](https://github.com/googlemaps/js-samples/blob/gh-pages/articles/phpsqlsearch/phpsqlsearch_data.sql) - This example data set contains 169 rows in total. If you follow the link above, you can copy the full data set in the following format:

```
INSERT INTO `markers` (`name`, `address`, `lat`, `lng`) VALUES ('Frankie Johnnie & Luigo Too','939 W El Camino Real, Mountain View, CA','37.386339','-122.085823');
INSERT INTO `markers` (`name`, `address`, `lat`, `lng`) VALUES ('Amici\'s East Coast Pizzeria','790 Castro St, Mountain View, CA','37.38714','-122.083235');
INSERT INTO `markers` (`name`, `address`, `lat`, `lng`) VALUES ('Kapp\'s Pizza Bar & Grill','191 Castro St, Mountain View, CA','37.393885','-122.078916');
INSERT INTO `markers` (`name`, `address`, `lat`, `lng`) VALUES ('Round Table Pizza: Mountain View','570 N Shoreline Blvd, Mountain View, CA','37.402653','-122.079354');
INSERT INTO `markers` (`name`, `address`, `lat`, `lng`) VALUES ('Tony & Alba\'s Pizza & Pasta','619 Escuela Ave, Mountain View, CA','37.394011','-122.095528');
INSERT INTO `markers` (`name`, `address`, `lat`, `lng`) VALUES ('Oregano\'s Wood-Fired Pizza','4546 El Camino Real, Los Altos, CA','37.401724','-122.114646');
INSERT INTO `markers` (`name`, `address`, `lat`, `lng`) VALUES ('Round Table Pizza: Sunnyvale-Mary-Central Expy','415 N Mary Ave, Sunnyvale, CA','37.390038','-122.042034');
INSERT INTO `markers` (`name`, `address`, `lat`, `lng`) VALUES ('Giordano\'s','730 N Rush St, Chicago, IL','41.895729','-87.625411');
INSERT INTO `markers` (`name`, `address`, `lat`, `lng`) VALUES ('Filippi\'s Pizza Grotto','1747 India St, San Diego, CA','32.723831','-117.168326');
INSERT INTO `markers` (`name`, `address`, `lat`, `lng`) VALUES ('Lou Malnati\'s Pizzeria','439 N Wells St, Chicago, IL','41.890346','-87.633927');
etc...
etc...
```

I hope this helps anyone who has struggled as much as I have. With just basic understanding of PHP and MySQL, you'll have this up and running in no time.

Good Luck!

Answer (score 1):

> I think the culprit lies somewhere in the calculation inside the $sql function.

Correct. But it's not what you are thinking.

You main problem is that your are using placeholder lie `:lat` in your select clause. [This comment](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php#111977) explains the problem well. But the bottom line is that you cant bind params in the SELECT and FROM clause because they are parsed before parameters are added.

Using PDO or MySQLi won't change that. So to add those variable into the SELECT clause, sanitize them properly and insert them as string in the query.

You're making use of one of my favorite features of PDO, the named placeholders. So I would suggest sticking with PDO.

To have any luck debugging a 500 error you need to check your server logs. Maybe `/var/log/apache2/error.log` if you have a typical LAMP stack.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I am no longer getting the error 500 (that was a $servername error on my part). I have also added in "or die(header("location:index.php#error1"));" on the "$points->execute($params);" operation. I am now being redirected with error1 showing up... That link was very interesting, however I'm ashamed to admit, I still haven't figured it out. I feel a little defeated to be honest - Is there any way you could give me an example of what my code *should* look like once I'm done?